# Count DataGridCells according to a boolean AttachedProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

I have e highlighting mechanism which changes the background of a DataGridCell according to a searched pattern.

```
<Setter Property="converters:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SearchValueConverter}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Content.Text"/>
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(converters:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue)" />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Column.Header" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And the trigger is defined as :

```
<Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="converters:DataGridTextSearch.IsTextMatch" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Code for that AttachedProperty:

```
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsTextMatch.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextMatchProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsTextMatch", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridTextSearch), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public static bool GetIsTextMatch(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsTextMatchProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsTextMatch(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsTextMatchProperty, value);
    }
```

I would like to count all the cells which have the IsTextMatch true. Further more i will need to count the rows, there might be many cells on one row so i will have to detect that but i am trying to go step by step.

I tried to add another Attached Property in my static class which will count how many "true" are set. I  updated its value from the PropertyChangedCallback of the IsTextMatchProperty but it didn't work.

This is the XAML to access that property :

```
  converters:DataGridTextSearch.CellsCount="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

where DataGridTextSearch is my static class in which the properties resides.

Is there any other approach? If not, what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic approach is to create a supervising object, say Counter, which is responsible for counting of highlighted cells.

```
public class Counter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    HashSet<DependencyObject> _hash = new HashSet<DependencyObject>();

    public void Add(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        this._hash.Add(obj);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Count");
    }

    public void Remove(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        this._hash.Remove(obj);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Count");
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this._hash.Count;
        }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation omitted...
}
```

Add an attached dependency property CellCounter to your behavior:

```
// get/set methods omitted

public static readonly DependencyProperty CounterProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "CellsCounter", 
    typeof(Counter), 
    typeof(GridBehavior), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GridBehavior.OnCellsCounterPropertyChanged));

private static void OnCellsCounterPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var oldCounter = e.OldValue as Counter;
    if (oldCounter != null)
    {
        oldCounter.Remove(d);
    }

    var newCounter = e.NewValue as Counter;
    if (newCounter != null)
    {
        var isSelected = GridBehavior.GetIsSelected(d);
        if (isSelected)
        {
            newCounter.Add(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Add logic of incrementing/decrementing of the counter to the IsTextMatch property:

```
// get/set methods omitted  

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextMatchProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsTextMatch", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(GridBehavior), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GridBehavior.OnIsTextMatchPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnIsTextMatchPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var counter = d.GetValue(GridBehavior.CellsCounterProperty) as Counter;
        if (counter == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            counter.Add(d);
        }
        else
        {
            counter.Remove(d);
        }
    }
```

Then you define a single counter in the Resources section of a window/control and poll the Count property wherever you want. Due to INotifyPropertyChanged nature of the counter all changes will be automatically dispatched to a counter's consumer. Like this (I used ListBox instead of DataGrid and didn't use a view model for simplicity but it doesn't matter):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">
    <Window.Resources>
        <view:Counter x:Key="CounterKey"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem view:GridBehavior.IsTextMatch="True"
                         view:GridBehavior.CellsCounter="{StaticResource CounterKey}"
                         Content="a"/>
            <ListBoxItem view:GridBehavior.IsTextMatch="False"
                         view:GridBehavior.CellsCounter="{StaticResource CounterKey}"
                         Content="b"/>
            <ListBoxItem view:GridBehavior.IsTextMatch="False"
                         view:GridBehavior.CellsCounter="{StaticResource CounterKey}"
                         Content="c"/>
            <ListBoxItem view:GridBehavior.IsTextMatch="True"
                         view:GridBehavior.CellsCounter="{StaticResource CounterKey}"
                         Content="d"/>
        </ListBox>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Count,Source={StaticResource CounterKey}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

N.B. You need to go further and carefully enhance Remove logic. For example, now if you remove an item with IsTextMatch=true from the list, it doesn't affect the counter. I believe, you are skilled enough to do this by yourself.